# Firebase cloud messaging console not showing android app configuration

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, push

I just created my very first firebase project using the firebase web console. It is an Android project. Under Firebase -> Settings -> General, I can see details of the Android project when I go to Firebase -> Settings -> Cloud Messaging, it does not show me the Android app configuration. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: same here, have you found a solution?